# how to use streams in play 2.6 with header

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

Recently I upgraded to play 2.6 from play 2.4 
i have this code

```
def prometheusMetrics = Action {
    val responseStream = Concurrent.unicast[Array[Byte]] { channel =>
      val writer = new WriterAdapter(channel)
      TextFormat.write004(writer, CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.metricFamilySamples())
      writer.close()
    }
    Ok.stream(responseStream).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)
  )

  }
```

in play 2.6 it generates compile time error

myproject/app/controllers/Application.scala:146: value stream is not a member of Application.this.Status
[error]     Ok.stream(responseStream).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)

so i changed the code like this

```
def prometheusMetrics = Action {
    val responseStream = Concurrent.unicast[Array[Byte]] { channel =>
      val writer = new WriterAdapter(channel)
      TextFormat.write004(writer, CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.metricFamilySamples())
      writer.close()
    }
    Result(
    header = ResponseHeader(200 -> Map("Content-Type" -> TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)),
    body = HttpEntity.Streamed(responseStream)
  )
  }
```

but again its giving a compile time error

```
myproject/app/controllers/Application.scala:148: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : (Int, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])
[error]  required: Int
[error]     header = ResponseHeader(200 -> Map("Content-Type" -> TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)),
[error]                                 ^
```

how can i add

```
"Content-Type" -> TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004
```

as a header here? what is a right way to do this?

Comment: Content type header must be set using `.as` on `Result`

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Please first read the documentation